# vs code Python extension dataframe not shown in output

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I just started using jupyter cells in Visual Studio Code through the Python extension. It is outputting plots fine, but my dataframe is not showing up like the [blog example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2018/11/08/data-science-with-python-in-visual-studio-code/) from Microsoft. Below is my code I am running in VS Code:

```
#%%
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))
plt.show()

#%%
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

My output looks like this:

[VS Code Cell outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tix8.png)

I am really excited to use jupyter in VS Code but I need to view the dataframes like in other variable explorers.

I am on windows using Anaconda as my environment.

- jupyter=1.0.0=py36_7
- jupyter_client=5.2.3=py36_0
- jupyter_console=6.0.0=py36_0
- jupyter_core=4.4.0=py36_0
- numpy=1.15.4=py36h19fb1c0_0
- pandas=0.23.4=py36h830ac7b_0

Comment: Can't reproduce your bug. `$Unknown MIME type for data` Could you upgrade VS Code and Python extension to latest Version, also mention platform(Windows/Linux) and python version, pandas version.  use this command  `conda list --export > allpythonpackages.txt`

Comment: Also update jupyter notebooks `python3 -m pip install --upgrade jupyter notebook`

Comment: I updated jupyter, pandas, and numpy in my python 3.6 environment that is separate from conda. If I use the python 3.6 environment in VS Code the output works correctly and displays the dataframe now, but the conda environment still shows the wrong output "$Unknown mime type for data". I also updated my conda but that doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: I checked my pip versions and compared them to my conda versions for the packages in the post. The only one that is different is jupyter_client=5.2.4 in my pip version. Could that be the cause? Sorry I am new and trying to explain everything the best that I can.

Answer (score 0):

That error means we don't have the capability to render the df output for some reason. 
The only thing I can think of is you might have a jupyter extension that's modifying the result of a df. (normally it returns an html table to us)

> Do you know what jupyter extensions you have installed?

Comment: Add the error please and some tags about your problem

Comment: I have quite a bit of extenstions installed in my VS Code, are you suggesting deleting some older ones and see if that fixes the issue?

Comment: This would be more appropriate as a comment. It doesn't quite answer the question.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more explicit. I meant jupyter extensions, like this one:
http://beakerx.com/

Not VS code extensions.  Other VS Code extensions wouldn't interfere with our Jupyter results.

Comment: I did have beakerx installed in my Anaconda 3.6 version.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled my Anaconda 3.6 and installed the newer Anaconda 3.7 and now it works in VS Code.

Comment: Still doesn't answer as to what caused the error. It seems to be a  conda issue but it could also have to do with jupyter_client library.